# MySQL JOIN ON a subquery?

Tags: mysql, sql, join, left-join, uuid

Table a looks like this:

```
uuid
----------------
0681a8ff0e114680b2688c538d92f3cb
148ba55922544c1b8ea8e7d43ffb8095
```

Table b looks like this:

```
uuid                                 | username
-----------------------------------------------
0681a8ff-0e11-4680-b268-8c538d92f3cb | test123
148ba559-2254-4c1b-8ea8-e7d43ffb8095 | poop123
ac123b2a-6546-8979-3213-cb426aac426b | blabla
```

How do I select all values from table a with their respective username? Note that table a has the UUIDs without the hyphens, while table b has them with hyphens. (Both are VARCHARS though)

I know how to select the UUIDs from table a with the dashes added:

```
SELECT CONCAT_WS('-',MID(uuid,1,8),MID(uuid,9,4),MID(uuid,13,4),MID(uuid,17,4),MID(uuid,21,1000))
```

I also know how to join two tables based on a column, but I can't figure out how to add the dashes and do the join all in one query.

Answer (score 2):

Just remove the hyphens in the `on` clause:

```
select . . .
from a join
     b
     on a.uuid = replace(b.uuid, '-', '');
```

Then, go back and figure out how to fix the original data.  Your keys should have the same type and format for foreign key references.

Comment: Can't believe I didn't think of that.. 

I solved it using
    `SELECT b.uuid, b.username FROM b JOIN a ON b.uuid = CONCAT_WS('-',MID(a.uuid,1,8),MID(a.uuid,9,4),MID(a.uuid,13,4),MID(a.uuid,17,4),MID(a.uuid,21,1000))`